# The shape of a numpy array is wrong after being saved

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on a ML project and I needed to save a numpy file. As my np array was too large, I had to split it in 3 pieces.

To save:

```
np.save('mfcc.npy', X[:10000])
np.save('mfcc2.npy', X[10000:20000])
np.save('mfcc3.npy', X[20000:])
```

To load:

```
features = np.load('mfcc.npy', allow_pickle=True) #récupération des données
feature_ = np.load('mfcc2.npy', allow_pickle=True)
features = np.append(features, feature_)
feature_ = np.load('mfcc3.npy', allow_pickle=True)
features = np.append(features, feature_)
```

My problem is that **the numpy array doesn't have the same shape anymore**:

```
print(features.shape)
#(30000, 24)
print(features[0].shape)
#(24,)
```

```
print(features.shape)
#(30000,)
print(features[0].shape)
#(820, 24)
```

I have no clue where does the "820" came from ? Help me if you can, please ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Without much more details about the shapes of your data, here's my suggestion:

You should use [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
mfcc1 = np.load('mfcc.npy', allow_pickle=True)
mfcc2 = np.load('mfcc2.npy', allow_pickle=True)
mfcc3 = np.load('mfcc3.npy', allow_pickle=True)

features = np.concatenate([mfcc1, mfcc2, mfcc3])

>>> features.shape, features[0].shape
(30000, 24) (24,)
```

As [`np.append`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) will tend to flatten your input:

```
features = np.append(mfcc1, mfcc2)

>>> features.shape, features[0].shape
(480000,) ()
```

Comment: No problem, let's try this: Could you first give me the type of `X` (use `X.dtype`) and its shape. Then  define `mfcc1`, `mfcc2`, and `mfcc3` as I did in my code above and print out the shapes of all three without performing any concatenation/append. We'll see from there!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, if someone weird like this happens to you, just check if you save the right array. It was just a mistake.